# opencv (Java) - matchTemplate unknown exception

Tags: java, opencv

Trying to using the matchTemplate method from `org.opencv.imgproc` but getting `java.lang.Exception: unknown exception` being thrown with no other details.

I'm calling it in the following way:

```
    private Mat matchTemplate(final Mat source) {

        final Mat sample = loadTemplate();

        final Mat result = new Mat();
        Imgproc.matchTemplate(source, sample, result, Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
        Imgproc.threshold(result, result, 0.1, 1, Imgproc.THRESH_TOZERO);

        return result;
    }
```

Where the values going into the template are:

- source: `Mat [ 1440*2560*CV_8UC3, isCont=true, isSubmat=false`
- sample: `Mat [ 22*46*CV_8UC3, isCont=true, isSubmat=false`
- result: `Mat [ -1*-1*CV_8UC1, isCont=false, isSubmat=false`

At first, I thought it was a mismatch between the source and sample but looking at what's going in it seems fine?

What else can I try or how can I get more information out of the error to debug this further?

**edit:**
So I just tried to normalize my inputs to see if that would help and noticed it crashes too on the same input. I'm now thinking I'm just building the source image incorrectly.

I'm capturing a screenshot using:

```
public class ScreenshotServiceImpl implements ScreenshotService {

    private final FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber;

    private final ToOrgOpenCvCoreMat toCore = new ToOrgOpenCvCoreMat();

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public Mat take() {

        grabber.start();
        final Mat output = toCore.convert(grabber.grab());
        grabber.stop();

        return output;
    }

}
```

Is it possible the convert is doing something weird to the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out closing the grabber early like I was doing was causing the problem. I naively assumed that when using the convert function I was making a copy of the value and no longer required it to be open.

To solve this while keeping the structure of my application I've updated the `take()` method:

```
  @Override
  @SneakyThrows
  public Mat take() {

    if (!grabber.isCloseInputStream()) {
      grabber.stop();
    }

    grabber.start();

    return toCore.convert(grabber.grabImage());
  }
```

This will leave the grabber frame open for further processing but close it off when taking another screenshot.

For my use case where I'm taking a screenshot every 50ms for a period then terminating the application this is fine. This definitely isn't the best approach for every use case so be careful with a blind copy-paste :D